# Realtek codec driver won't install - keeps "uninstalling"

Tags: windows-10, drivers, codec, realtek-hd-audio

So I downloaded the latest Realtek codec driver (Win10, 64-Bit) and after running the installer, it says that the current one must first be uninstalled for the new one to be installed.

Ok. Let the wizard do its thing. Restarted my PC.

But after logging into windows again, the Realtek wizard appears again, saying that the current one must first be uninstalled for the new one to be installed.

I restarted my PC like 5 times now but nothing changes.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For 32-bit applications installed onto 64-bit Operating System, browse to the following:

```
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

For 64-bit applications installed onto 64-bit Operating System or 32-bit applications installed onto 32-bit Operating System, browse to the following:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

And remove the voice seems to "Realtek"

If folder does not exist, then search in each folder with UUID if there are values with that name.

Comment: EDIT: Ok, I found it (you REALLY could've told me you were referring to the Registry Editor), but i dont have the Realtek folder

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue updating to drivers 6.0.8945.1, here's how I solved it:

1. Open the device manager
2. Open the category 'Sound, video, and game controllers'
3. Right click on the entry for 'Realtek(R) Audio' and uninstall
4. Restart the PC
5. When the wizard reappears, it should should finish normally

Note that some ports managed by the Realtek driver may appear in 'Audio inputs and outputs' but claim to be controlled by a Microsoft driver, but this seems to be normal, the Realtek Audio Console can still detect and control them.

Comment: My goal was to have that "enhancements" tab when looking at the settings for my microphone. It still doesnt show up, but at least the wizard stopped bugging me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are running into the automatic driver installation on Windows. Something I've run into myself in the past with AMD drivers.

CMD run

```
sysdm.cpl
```

This will bring up the 'System Properties' window. Go to the 'Hardware' tab, and click on 'Device INstallation Settings' button. Set the option to 'no' and then 'save changes'. After that, try re-install your drivers.

Comment: Won't that  disable all device updates

Comment: Yea, but at least you could see if that's the issue. That would give you a starting point. 

If that works turn back on that option and then you can go into the driver under "Device Manager" and do a Roll Back Driver.

Answer (score -1):

@Mark c - what kind of computer, motherboard or system are you using?

the "enhancements" tab is only available when installing standard or non-DCH based Realtek audio drivers.  the Realtek drivers provided by the computer manufacturer or motherboard maker might be in the modern DCH or UAD driver format which will NOT produce the "enhancements" tab for Realtek audio.  you will need to download Realtek Audio Console or Realtek Audio Control from the MS store and run that to access the microphone settings instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).